# How to backup mysql database with where condition?

Tags: mysql

As a superadmin I want to take backup of whole database with giving where condition. Like `where accoutid = 88`. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where clauses apply to tables, not databases.  So you can backup tables with where clauses.  Since the mysqldump syntax excludes tables not explicitly listed in the mysqldump command, you won't get the entire database unless you list every table in the db explicitly (which you could do).

[Here is the mysqldump documentation.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)

[This answer will explain what to do.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/4659)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this,

mysqldump --host=localhost --user=db_user --password= db_pass db_name table_name --no_create_info --where=accoutid=88 > data.sql